# Can I create an application which ask for user's gdrive id and password, and than upload files from local computer to gdrive automatically?

Tags: api, google-drive-api

Yes, I get it what I am asking for is exactly how gdrive works, in fact coping multiple files is also a simple ctrl+A and drag and drop. But still humor me, can I use gdrive API to ask for end user's ID and Password, and it uploads certain files in the user gdrive. The files it would upload is basically already hardcoded, like all the pdf files from a certain directory.

I am an undergrad student and really not familiar with the workings of API, so thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can!

Start with the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) on your favorite language and then reference this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) to understand how to upload a file.

Hope this helps!